# Can I conclude that the following map is surjective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I have a module homomorphism $A \rightarrow B \oplus C $ whose projection onto the first factor $B$ is surjective. If the projection onto $C$ is surjective and $C$ is a simple module, can I conclude that my map is surjective?

Comment: No. Just take $A = B = C = \mathbb{Z}_p$. Define $\varphi : A \to B \oplus C$ by $\varphi(n) = (n,0)$.

Comment: Sorry I added an extra detail.

Comment: It's still not true. Again take $A = B = C = \mathbb{Z}_p$. Define $\varphi : \mathbb{Z}_p \to \mathbb{Z}_p \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p$ by $\varphi(n) = (n,n)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Take your favourite simple module and consider the map $A\to A\oplus A$ given by $a\mapsto (a,a) $. Then the projection onto both factors is surjective (indeed it is bijective). This map is no bijection, however as you can readily verify.